# dynamic mixins in ruby on rails model based on variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mixins

I have very specific task. I need a model that can extend itself based on variable. In my example its s model that fetches json and saves part of it, but it can be more complicated than that (xml to json conversion for example).

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'open-uri'

    serialize :data, JSON

    def downlaod!
        # self.url = "http://jsonview.com/example.json"
        result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)

        # self.mixin = "api_v_3"
        if mixin.present?
            self.class.send :include, Feed.const_get(mixin.camelize)
            store_data(result)
        end

        save!
    end
end
```

and my mixin:

```
module ApiV3
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def store_data(data)
        self.data = data['anobject']
        self.class.send :undef_method, :store_data
    end
end
```

So when i call:

```
feed.download!
```

it includes mixin and do some stuff. I'm looking for a better way doing it, seems too complicated and unreliable. Any advise, tutorial or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you decide include it into model? for using some common interface/method like `store_data` you don't need include it to model

Comment: there is like 10 mixins for 200 or so records. and `store_data` can be much more complicated. code above is just an example. actual mixins is about 50 lines of code. where should i include them then?